# Android, get latitude, longitude (wifi) and device ID

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

Is there any way to get latitude and longitude from the device without using the GPS? I would also like to know if theres a way to get some kind of serial number or similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get your network/WIFI based location using the network provider property of the LocationManager class.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

Where listener is an implementation of the android.location.LocationListener class.

For your second question, you can get the WIFI MAC address which is pretty unique, although I'm not sure what happens if the device doesn't have WIFI.

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String macAddress = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

Note that this requires you to add the following to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: If it doesn't have WiFi, one would assume the `WifiInfo` object returned from `wm.getConnectionInfo()` would be `null`, no?  In which case, you'd want to do a null-check there before calling `getMacAddress()` so you don't get a NRE.

Comment: I'd think the same. All I'm trying to say is that I'm not sure, so it's a good idea to run a couple of tests instead of basing your code on an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

Try to use the networkprovider...

Here you can find some information related to that:
http://androidforums.com/samsung-i7500/9257-using-wireless-networks-location.html

About a serial number i don't know... maybe you can use some kind of MAC adress...